# Template argument functions as class members

Tags: c++, class, templates, initialization, member

I have a lot of methods defined in `Transforms.h` like this :

```cpp
#ifndef TRANSFORMS_H
#define TRANSFORMS_H

namespace Transforms
{
    long double asech(long double x);
    long double acsch(long double x);
    long double asechDerivative(long double x);
    long double acschDerivative(long double x);
    long double identity(long double x);
    long double identityDerivative(long double x);
};
#endif //!TRANSFORMS_H
```

And I tried creating a templated class like this:

```cpp
// Layer.h
template<typename Forward, typename Backward>
class Layer
{
protected:
    Matrix* previousActivation{ nullptr }, * error{ nullptr }, * delta{ nullptr };
    Matrix& weights;
    Vector& bias;
public:
    const int inputs, neurons;
    Forward applyActivation;
    Backward applyActivationDerivative;

    Layer(int inputs, int neurons, Matrix& weights, Vector& bias);
    ~Layer();

    Matrix& activate(Matrix& x);

    /*virtual Matrix& applyActivation(Matrix& x) = 0;
    virtual Matrix& applyActivationDerivative(Matrix& x) = 0;*/
};
```

to try and be able to create new layers by just doing

```cpp
class Sigmoid: public Layer<sigmoid, sigmoidDerivative>;
```

that way I won't have to override using pure virtual methods. But I can't seem to figure out how to set the member variables `applyActivation` and `applyActivationDerivative` inside the `Layer` constructor

I'm also new to templates in C++ and I come from Java so please bear with me.

Comment: Damn i made so many mistakes, thanks for taking the time to edit @cigien !

Comment: No problem :) They were just minor typos, you didn't make any serious mistakes :)

Comment: *"won't have to override the pure virtual methods"* -- Why are you using pure virtual functions? The point of a function being pure virtual is that it *does* have to be overridden.

Comment: @JaMiT yeah but then every derived class i write would need me to actually write boilerplate code to override them each time =s If i can make them member variables that get set from template arguments i would be able to create derived classes using 1 line =O

Comment: *"I can't seem to figure out how to set [something]"* -- it might help to write out what to set those things to (perhaps in a simple case, if the general case is overwhelming). Also write out how the constructor would know what to set those things to.

Comment: @Lorenzo That information is not apparent in your question. You skipped the part where you had a version that worked with pure virtual function (or did it not work?) and are now trying to replace the functions with member variables. You probably should take some time to write out what you want instead of assuming people can accurately guess based upon your code. Code should illustrate your question, not be the primary source of information.

Comment: @JaMiT The code with the overrides worked the only problem was that for each derived class i had to write the actual definition of each overriden method, and that's just boilerplate code that i wanted to avoid to write. My problem was how to use the functions/functors passed as template arguments and i tried explaining my problem as whole because i clearly didn't have the best solution (of using member variables) as shown by John Zwinck's answer

Comment: A missed opportunity for clarity: you provided declarations for six example transforms, yet your example for creating new layers uses transforms that were not declared. Why have your example class use `sigmoid` and `sigmoidDerivative` instead of functions that were declared? Consistency is often helpful when clarity is desired.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been consistent. The transforms header file is 400 lines long, and i thought it made sense since all my transformations come in pairs (with their derivatives). I'll make a better question post next time

Comment: @Lorenzo Regarding the overrides: That is the sort of information I think you should include in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass *values* not *types* as your template arguments.  Here is a reduced example using your code with all the unnecessary details removed and a couple methods added to demonstrate the usage of the template parameters.

```
long double sigmoid(long double x);
long double sigmoidDerivative(long double x);

using FuncT = long double(*)(long double);

template<FuncT Forward, FuncT Backward>
class Layer
{
public:
    long double applyForward(long double x) { return Forward(x); }
    long double applyBackward(long double x) { return Backward(x); }
};

class Sigmoid : public Layer<sigmoid, sigmoidDerivative> {};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/99h54a

Comment: Oh so my problem was that i was not specifying the template type ? =o The `using` keyword here is only to "redefine"/renam the type right ?

Comment: The `using` is to declare a short name for a pointer to a function.  You could write that out in each template parameter instead of `FuncT` but it would be ugly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! That was exactly what i wanted